# Android Studio’s Emulators don’t run properly after moving SDK folder

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, libpng

I moved SDK folder to another directory of my computer and after that when I run my app, none of my emulators execute as the way they previously run. For example, when I choose Pixel_2_API_28, instead of it, [a device like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdMdz.png) executes and my app doesn’t run on it.

Also, Event Log shows this message: **“Emulator: Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile ((null):0, (null))”**

I really appreciate any help to fix this problem.